# How can I tell if my laptop is being charged in Python?

Tags: python, ctypes

I have been working on some python code that does heavy calculations, and it's finally finished. I am now running the code as much as possible, but because it uses a constant +- 70% processor and 1,5Gb ram it uses a lot of power. For this reason i only run the script when i am charging my laptop, but i often forget.

What i want to do to solve this problem is making it automatic, of course. My plan is to always have the script running, but when my laptop is not charging it will be idle.

The main problem with this is that i have to detect that my laptop is being charged. I have looked around for information on this, but i can't find any that suits my problem. I have seen people use the ctypes library, but i can't seem to find a function that tells me if my laptop is being charged.

I am looking for a python function that tells me if my laptop is being charged.

edit: My operating system is windows 10.

Comment: What OS you are using ?

Comment: Assuming you are running linux, http://askubuntu.com/questions/69556/how-to-check-battery-status-using-terminal

Comment: oh, i forgot to tell. I am running windows, mainly because this is my school laptop.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/power